# list only direct child directories of all directories with a particular name

Tags: bash, find

I have a directory structure like the following:

```
.
├── Untitled Folder
│   ├── Untitled Folder
│   │   └── zing
│   │       ├── first
|   |       |   └── dum
│   │       ├── second
│   │       └── third
│   ├── Untitled Folder 2
│   └── Untitled Folder 3
├── Untitled Folder 2
│   ├── Untitled Folder
│   ├── Untitled Folder 2
│   │   └── zing
│   │       ├── fifth
|   |       |   └── dum
│   │       ├── fourth
│   │       └── sixth
│   └── Untitled Folder 3
└── Untitled Folder 3
    ├── Untitled Folder
    ├── Untitled Folder 2
    └── Untitled Folder 3
        └── zing
            ├── eighth
            └── seventh
                └── dum
```

I want to list only direct child directories of all `zing` directories.

Sample output is:

```
first
second
third
fifth
fourth
sixth
eighth
seventh
```

I tried

```
% find . -type d | grep zing
./Untitled Folder 3/Untitled Folder 3/zing
./Untitled Folder 3/Untitled Folder 3/zing/eigthth
./Untitled Folder 3/Untitled Folder 3/zing/seventh
./Untitled Folder 3/Untitled Folder 3/zing/seventh/dum
./Untitled Folder 2/Untitled Folder 2/zing
./Untitled Folder 2/Untitled Folder 2/zing/fifth
./Untitled Folder 2/Untitled Folder 2/zing/fifth/dum
./Untitled Folder 2/Untitled Folder 2/zing/fourth
./Untitled Folder 2/Untitled Folder 2/zing/sixth
./Untitled Folder/Untitled Folder/zing
./Untitled Folder/Untitled Folder/zing/first
./Untitled Folder/Untitled Folder/zing/first/dum
./Untitled Folder/Untitled Folder/zing/third
./Untitled Folder/Untitled Folder/zing/second
```

It is even showing the child of the child of `zing` (in this case `dum`), which I do not want.

How can I get my expected output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Bash, Globstar activated (with `shopt -s globstar`).

  ```
  printf '%s\n' **/zing/*/
  ```

  - For only the last path component,

    ```
     for dir in **/zing/*/; do basename "$dir"; done
    ```
- POSIX Find.

  ```
  find . -type d -path '*/zing/*' -prune
  ```

  `-prune` avoids descending in the matched directories.

  - For only the last path component,

    ```
    find . -type d -path '*/zing/*' -prune -exec basename {} \;
    ```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
find . -type d -regex ".*/zing/[^/]+"
```

Comment: Very nice use of the GNU's `-regex` flag! The asker can add `-exec basename {} \;` to remove the path components of the output if that is indeed a must.

Comment: Or `-printf '%f\n'`

Answer (score 0):

You could find all *zing* directories

```
find . -type d -name zing
```

and execute a "ls" in each if you need to get the directory's contents.

Or maybe iterate the find (`find \{\} -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1`) to get only the immediate child directory names. Then you can use `basename` to get only the directory name, or some ugly hack like `| rev | cut -f1 -d/ | rev`.